# How do I convert this script to a js file?

Tags: javascript

I have this script that I need as a .js file, so I can use it multiple times without having multiple copies of the script everywhere, like calliing the script YTiFramePlayer.js. But, maybe I want to change promoVideo, or videoId. How would I do that?

```
//YouTube iframe player
//Load the iframe Player API
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('promoVideo', {
height: '390',
width: '640',
videoId: '00000',
events: {
         'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
});
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.STOPPED) {
stopVideo();
}
}

function startVideo() {
$("#video").css("height", "calc(100vh - 48px)");
player.playVideo();
}

function stopVideo() {
player.stopVideo();
$("#video").css("height", "0px");
}
```

Comment: Isn't it already JS file?

Comment: So you have JavaScript code, and you need it to be... JavaScript code?  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It's not a JS file. I guess I could make it .js, but how would I call the player with videoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save this as a .js file as mentioned previously, but wrap the functionality in a global variable that you can access elsewhere.  Example:

script.js:

```
//YouTube iframe player
//Load the iframe Player API
var ytPlayer = (function() {
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  var videoId;
  var promoVideo = 'promoVideo';
  var player;

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  return {
    init(id, promoVideo) {
      videoId = id;
      promoVideo = promoVideo;
      onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
    }
  }

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    console.log('Setting up:', videoId, promoVideo)
    player = new YT.Player(promoVideo, {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: videoId,
      events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.STOPPED) {
      stopVideo();
    }
  }

  function startVideo() {
    $("#video").css("height", "calc(100vh - 48px)");
    player.playVideo();
  }

  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
    $("#video").css("height", "0px");
  }
})();
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <script>
      ytPlayer.init('a8a83sda', 'someOtherId')
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

See the [revealing module pattern](http://jargon.js.org/_glossary/REVEALING_MODULE_PATTERN.md) for more information.

Comment: ytPlayer.init('a8a83sda', 'someOtherId') - What is a8a83sda? What is someOtherId?

Comment: @AwesomeTech10 They are the videoId of the promoVideo id ('promoVideo'). You can pass in whatever you need. The init function is defined in the js: `init(id, promoVideo)`

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just save as with filename.js extension